# PHP and Oci8 - strange behavior - It seems to reuse the connection, even when it is not permanent

Tags: php, database, oracle, oci8

In this project a connection is made to a Oracle database.

When I load the page for the first time the database connection requires a bit of time (about 5 seconds). If then reloading the page the connection is instantaneous.

If, however, expect a few minutes and then reloading the page the connection again need 5 seconds.

This behavior seems to indicate some sort of connection pooling, but the connection used is not permanent.

I also tried using the function `oci_new_connect` so as to always force the creation of a new connection, but the behavior remains the same.

Is it normal for the first time the connection requires so much time?
Can help me understand why not take the same time every time?

**UPDATE**

I did a simple test.
A page with only this code:

```
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    $res = oci_new_connect('usr', 'pwd', 'constr', 'AL32UTF8', null);
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $execution_time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo $execution_time."<br>";
}
```

When i load the page the result is:

```
5.04553
0.04267
0.04366
[...]
0.04316
```

If i reload the page immediately the result is:

```
0.04432
0.04338
0.04802
[...]
0.04424
```

If I wait just two minutes before reloading the page the result is again that of the first case.
it seems that reuses the connection even if the `oci_new_connect` method is used.

This behavior should not occur only with a permanent connection?

Comment: i think it is server response time issue .

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh thanks for replying, it seems strange that only happens the first time in a series of requests and again if I wait a few minutes